# How to Determine if a Document was Actually Changed During Update in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates

I am using the Mongoose driver with NodeJS. I have quite a simple update call whose purpose is to sync an external source of meetings to my database:

```
collection.update({ meeting_id: doc.meeting_id}, newDoc, {upsert:true})
```

The object returned determines whether or not an update or an insert occurred. This works perfectly. My issue is that I must determine if an actual change occurred. When you update a document with itself, MongoDB treats this in exactly the same way as if all fields were changed.

So my question is: Is there any good way to tell if anything actually changed? I could search for each document then compare each field manually, but this seems like a poor (and slow) solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use findAndModify which will return updated results as compared to update which will return no of updated records.

```
collection.findAndModify(
    { meeting_id: doc.meeting_id},
    newDoc,
    { new: true },
    function (err, documents) {
        res.send({ error: err, affected: documents });

    }
);
```

Comment: And how do you tell if newDoc is not equal to the old document? This does not address my issue.

Comment: you can use JSON.stringify(oldDoc) === JSON.stringify(newDoc)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that is better (faster) than finding the old doc and comparing the fields. As stated in my question I'm syncing two independent data sources, so oldDoc is not available.